# Put message in p:growl from bean with Primefaces7.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 7.0, and I have a problem with passing messages from my bean to `p:growl` declared in XHTML.

```xml
<ns:grid-item width="100">
    <p:fileUpload id="fileupload"
                    label="#{msg['page.application-decisions.selectFile']}"
                    value="#{decisionBean.uploadedFile}"
                    style="display: flex; "
                    styleClass="button like-link font-14 -margin-bottom-20"
                    mode="advanced"
                    multiple="false"
                    auto="true"
                    dragDropSupport="false"
                    sizeLimit="10000000"
                    invalidSizeMessage="#{msg['page.application-decisions.invalidSizeMessage']}"
                    invalidFileMessage="#{msg['page.application-decisions.invalidFileMessage']}"
                    fileLimitMessage="#{msg['page.application-decisions.fileLimitMessage']}"
                    fileUploadListener="#{decisionBean.handleFileUpload}"
                    disabled="#{decisionBean.application.anyDecisionNotNotified==true}"
                    update="filemsg fileupload uploadedFileName @this">
    </p:fileUpload>
    <p:outputLabel id="uploadedFileName"
                    value="#{msg['page.application-decisions.uploadedFileName']}: #{decisionBean.uploadedFileName}"/>
    <p:growl id="filemsg" for="filemsg" showDetail="false"/>
    <br/>
</ns:grid-item>
```

bean:

```java
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    if (event.getFile().getFileName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
        this.uploadedFile = event.getFile();
    } else {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage("filemsg", new FacesMessage("asdas", "asdasd"));
    }
}
```

After uploading, for example, .jpg file, my message is displaying in my other `p:growl`, not in `filemsg` declared in else in my bean.

Do You know how to put my message into `filemsg` growl?

Comment: PF version? How is the other growl(autoUpdate, etc)?